# c syntax help - very basic

Tags: c, syntax

If we have

```
char *val = someString;
```

and then say

```
if(val){
    ....
}
```

what is the `if` statement actually checking here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` statement is equivalent to:

```
if (val != NULL) { ...
```

The comp.lang.c FAQ contains [this question and answer](http://c-faq.com/null/ptrtest.html) which goes into a bit more detail why this is true.

Comment: @Felixyz: You're right, that was unnecessary wording. I've added a link to more detail.

Answer (score 2):

It's checking to see `if (val != 0)`.  In C all non-zero values are true, zero is false.

Answer (score 2):

`val` is a pointer to a char. This can be set to any address -valid or invalid-. The if statement will just check whether val is not null:

`if(val)`

is equivalent to

`if(NULL != val)`

is equivalent to

`if((void*)0 != val)`

Still, the pointer can point to an invalid location, for example memory that is not in the address space of your application. Therefore, is is very important to initialize pointers to 0, otherwise they will point to undefined locations. In a worst-case scenario, that location might be *valid* and you won't notice the error.

Answer (score 1):

It is testing if val contains the NULL pointer. If you had said,

```
char * val = NULL;

if ( val ) {
  ...
}
```

the test would fail.

Answer (score 1):

whether the val is a null pointer or not.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is checking if `val`, which is the same as `someString`, is non-`NULL`. Generally `if (v)` is a shortcut for `if (v!=0)`.

Answer (score 1):

> It is just checking val is NULL or not .

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it is checking whether the char pointer is not NULL. If you want to check if the string is not empty, try [strlen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen).

Answer (score 0):

val is a pointer, that statement is equal to if(val !=0), whereas 0 is also defined as NULL, so it will check whether that pointer is pointing to NULL address, keep in mind that NULL string pointer is not the same as empty string

Answer (score 0):

The above if condition is checking whether the pointer is pointing to non-null string.If that pointer points to any non-null string,then the condition will be true.Else,false.